# shared_ptr reference count changed after passed to a unique_ptr object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm fairly new to smart pointers and I couldn't understand the result of the code I attached below. Basically the reference count and the raw pointer it self of a `shared_ptr` object is changed after it is passed to another `unique_ptr` object.

So the code goes like this.

```cpp
typedef shared_ptr<int> sp;                                                        
class bar {                                                                        
 public:                                                                           
  const sp& x; // line 3: if change this line to "const sp x;" then it's fine                                                           
  bar(const sp xx) : x(xx) {                                                       
    cout << "bar:  count=" << x.use_count() << "; addr=" << x.get() << endl;       
  }                                                                                
  void test() {                                                                    
    cout << "test: count=" << x.use_count() << "; addr=" << x.get() << endl;       
  }                                                                                
};                                                                                 
int main() {                                                                       
  auto p = make_shared<int>(0);                                                    
  auto b = make_unique<bar>(p);                                                    
  b->test();                                                                       
}
```

If I compile and run the code, it prints out:

```
bar:  count=2; addr=0x557c8b02dec0
test: count=1224736736; addr=0x7ffdb5cbd5c0
```

So the ref count and pointer are both changed. And it looks like some uninitialized value.

But if I change line 3 to `const sp x;` then both values look normal:

```
bar:  count=3; addr=0x5590f026eec0
test: count=2; addr=0x5590f026eec0
```

Sorry about the bad namings since it's a quick minimum case I came up with to address my question. I feel it has something to do with how `unique_ptr` works, but I'm not sure.

Can someone shed some light and help me understand why the code behaves like that?

Thanks

Comment: Here `bar(const sp xx) : x(xx)` you keep a reference to a local variable `xx` that goes out of scope after the constructor call, this is undefined behavior. If you change `const sp x`, it copies `xx` and it is a well defined code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
const sp& x;                                                           
bar(const sp xx) : x(xx)
```

You assign the shared pointer into a local variable, `xx`, and then bind the const reference `x` to *that* local variable. When the constructor concludes its run, that local variable goes out of scope, leaving you with a reference to Eldritch Horrors and undefined behavior.

To explain your observation regarding the removal of the `&`:
Removing the `&` prevents this because in that case you just assign the shared pointer straight into `x` which henceforth is not dependent on the local variable `xx`, and so is unaffected by its going out of scope.

To expand: another thing you could do instead, if what you wanted was to hold a reference, is to set `xx` to be a reference itself (i.e `bar(const sp& xx) : x(xx)`); in this case you'd be binding `x` to `p`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's crystal clear. One more thing I tried is changing line 13 `auto b = make_unique` to `auto b = make_shared` , then the result seems well defined as well. What makes difference in this case? Thanks.

Comment: I'm happy to hear, @XiaofaPiao :) Regarding your question: this shouldn't make a difference as far as UB goes – you would still be binding a reference to a local variable that then gets discarded, and then accessing it. Seeing as this is UB, it's difficult to predict/explain exactly why things happen as they do: it's just happenstance based on implementation details. Maybe it's something about the difference in clean-up of a shared ptr vs a unique ptr. If you're interested, you can try running Valgrind to confirm that there's still an invalid read, even if the output seems ok in this case.

Comment: Actually, for more convincing results, you could just do something that's likely to shift things around. For instance, right before `b->test();`, add `auto t = make_shared<int>(0);` and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and indeed, valgrind yields "Invalid read" error and adding `auto t = ...` prints out the same wild numbers as before. Thank you for your help!